# shap.plots.scatter(shap_val[:, "featA"]) visualises continuous data as categorical data

Tags: python, scatter-plot, shap

The shap.plots.scatter(shap_val[:, "featA"]) wrongly visualises continuοus data as categorical data. The light grey area at the bottom of the shap plot is a histogram showing the distribution of data values. But the histogram visualises the distribution as if data are classes (it has two bins).
Q1) Why is this the case? Why don't it visualise the continuous data properly?
The figure below shows the shap.scatter: 
[image]

Below, you can see the proper distribution:
[image] (t)

Note that other continuous data distributions, for example data varying from [85, 115] are visualised properly. Categorical data are visualised properly the same. This is very strange and cannot explain why.

Additionally:
Q2) Why x-axis does not automatically take the feature's values, which vary from [0, 1] and shows even negative values?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The plot shows a histogram, which obviously depends on certain parameters (that e.g. depend on the data distribution and the number of points). Depending on the bin construction algo, the range of the histogram can be larger than the data range.

Comment: hi @MichaelM I think that is the solution, right! I had a deep look on the code, and it seems that the number of the bins in this case is 2, because of certain parameters. That is a pity, though, because in this case this is very confusing.

Comment: Making beautiful *and* generic plots is tricky... Maybe you can switch off the univariate plotting and add your own histogram to the axis.